# How to stop a Google map from drawing a second rectangle after a button is clicked

Tags: maps, rectangles

I am using a the following code to draw a rectangle on the map to a random lat. & long. based on a city name when a find button is clicked. The problem is if you do not put a different city name in and click the find button the program will draw a second rectangle on the cities original lat. & long. I either need to clear the map and redraw the rectangle or something not quite sure so a second rectangle can not be drawn. Here is the code I am using.

```
    function codeAddress() {
        var address = document.getElementById("gadres").value;

        if(address=='') {
            alert("Address can not be empty!");
            return;

        }


        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                document.getElementById('lat').value=results[0].geometry.location.lat().toFixed(6);
                document.getElementById('lng').value=results[0].geometry.location.lng().toFixed(6);
                var latlong = "(" + results[0].geometry.location.lat().toFixed(6) + " , " +
                + results[0].geometry.location.lng().toFixed(6) + ")";

                map.setZoom(15);

                var mapcenter = map.getCenter();
                var maplat = mapcenter.lat();
                var maplng = mapcenter.lng();

                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                    new google.maps.LatLng(maplat - 0.002, maplng - 0.002),
                    new google.maps.LatLng(maplat + 0.002, maplng + 0.002)
                );

                var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
                    bounds: bounds,
                    draggable:true,
                    editable: true,
                    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                    strokeWeight: 4,
                    fillColor: '#FF0000',
                    fillOpacity: 0.30,
                });

                rectangle.setMap(map);

                google.maps.event.addListener(rectangle, 'bounds_changed', function() {
                    document.getElementById('coords').value = rectangle.getBounds();

                });


            } else {
                alert("Lat and long cannot be found.");
            }
        }); 

    }
```

all help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this yet but perhaps you can store your bounds to an array then use a loop statement for that array to check if there is an equal bounds using the equals() method 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds

Comment: I solved the problem I used rectangle.setMap(null); so now there is only one rectangle and when they click the find button only one appears. Thanks for the help